# Protect bus and remaning bus-attached devices for bus-attached device failure (CANBus)

Tags: protection, can, bus

What are options to protect CANBus from failure of device connected to bus?
For example if CAN Transceiver pulls bus high or low. Or some other sort of electronics failure.

Thx

Comment: Protect from what kind of failures? Do you mean that devices do not get damaged by overvoltage but the bus does not need to work and it is stuck until offending device removed? What other electronic failures you mean?

Comment: No I want bus to continue working. Well primarily I am talking about pulling CANbus to ground or 5V because of component failure or some other type of component failure that will render bus unusable.

Comment: Any decent CAN transceiver will have a dominant (bus stuck) timeout to disconnect a faulty transmitter, and the CAN controller includes a lot of protection against a node creating havoc. That should be enough for most applications. Beyond this you could create your own watchdog, though it would be a bit tricky to determine that a particular node was causing the problem unless you did things like measure the line current.

Comment: If I get this right CAN transceiver is protecting you bus from Tx Rx pin failures but it cannot do nothing in case of CAN_H or CAN_L being connected to GND or 5V.
Thx for help.
I also found this post on TI forum.
https://e2e.ti.com/support/interface-group/interface/f/interface-forum/535103/switch-to-disconnect-can-node-during-disconnect

Comment: Failures on the MCU side are hard to protect against. A short somewhere on the Tx Rx and it may pull the whole bus to the wrong state. I remember some old project where we had accidentally placed a pull resistor on one of those signals, leading to the whole bus getting pulled to the wrong dominant state.

Comment: I agree but if CAN transceiver have  dominant timeout it should be no problem.
@Lundin

Comment: It might cause error frames regardless.

Comment: Ofc. But it should be fine in mine design.